# How to plot a chart with known column index in vba

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, graph, charts

I am trying to create a simple userform to plot graphs of selected columns.

What I did so far is shown in the code below:

```
Public Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim Axis As Variant
    Dim Axis1 As Variant

    Axis = Rows(1).Value

    ' here I'm filling the Comboboxes with all the names in the 1st row
    ComboBox1.Column = Axis
    ComboBox2.Column = Axis
End Sub
```

---

```
Public Sub Plot_Click()
    With Range("A1:ZZ1")
        'Here I'm searching for the column index of the selected value in the first Combobox
        Set rFind1 = .Find(What:=ComboBox1.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                           MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    End With
    Spalte1 = rFind1.Column

    With Range("A1:ZZ1")
       'Here I'm searching for the column index of the selected value in the second Combobox
        Set rFind2 = .Find(What:=ComboBox2.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole, _ 
                           MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    End With
    Spalte2 = rFind2.Column

    'somewhere here, I would like to plot a graph with the selected 
    'column indexes (Spalte1 and Spalte2) 

End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub Schliessen_Click()
    'here I'm closing the userform
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

The graph should look like this:

[image]

And in the future, I will also add some more Comboboxes in order to select more axis to plot

I appreciate every single answer/help and suggestion

Answer (score 0):

1. The way, you are initializing the ComboBox will add many blank items which will become cumbersome while selecting required value. I will suggest to add only required columns  instead.
2. Searching the selected column index again and again is also meaningless. You can use `.ListIndex` property to get 0 based index value. Hence the actual column index will be ComboBox1.ListIndex + 1 in case.
3. As you may require to add more ComboBox in future, I would rather suggest to use two ListBoxes, first with all column names and second will get updated with require columns to be used as series using Add, Remove buttons as following screenshot:
   [image: sample image]

Comment: Thanks for your advise @Dhirendra I will change the UserFrom as you suggest. I am just a beginner :)      But my actual question how to plot a graph with several selected columns is still not answered. I would appreciate if you could give me some ideas. Thanks